# It it worth to use a Dict with only keys and null values?

Tags: python, dictionary, hashmap

So in my niche use case I want to create a hash map in python to store a large list dataset. This list has a key value as a tuple (i.e `(1,2)`) and my goal is to search the list and see if the tuple exists.

I know this is achievable with a regular list but I wanted the time complexity of O(1) with the hash map functionality. But when adding elements to the dictionary, I am doing this:

```
dictionary[(1,2)] = None
```

Because I couldn't care less about the value associated with the key.

Is this good coding practice or is there something else I should use?

Comment: Can you not use a set?

Comment: What you describe is simply a set.  Please work through a tutorial on that topic.

Comment: Set is exactly what I am looking for. Thank you. I am very new to python and was immediately referred to use dictionaries in python from my friends.

Comment: You need new friends.

Comment: we are all newcomers don't worry about it. It was embarassing to ask but hey better to be embarrassed  than not know.

Comment: My question is coming up as not focussed. How can I improve my question? I am concerned I might get blocked as some users don't like my questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't give a toss about the value, you can use a set. From the python source code (line 4 of Objects/setobject.c):

> Derived from Lib/sets.py and Objects/dictobject.c.

If you need to iterate over a set, you should use a list or do the conversion as needed.

Comment: I'm sorry, what's the point of quoting this line of the source code?

Comment: You can iterate over a set directly, no need to convert it to a list or anything else.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `defaultdict`. By default, any values not in the dictionary would be `False`.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

lookup = defaultdict(bool)

lookup[(1,2)] = True
```

Examples:

```py
l = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
for e in l:
    lookup[e] = True

print(lookup[(3,4)])
# True
print(lookup[(8, 9)])
# False
```